# Using string as Named Table for Range Object

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of text values each of which is the name of a Named Table on a different Worksheet of my Workbook.

```
Colum1    Value
Table1    True
Table2    False
Table3    False
Table4    True
Table5    True
```

My VBA code is going through the list like so:

```
For Each cell In MyRange
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "True" Then
        Call WriteTXTFile(cell.Value)
    End If
Next cell
```

The WriteTXTFile subroutine needs to take the Table name and use it as a range to get all the data from the table and export it as a pipe-delimited TXT file like so:

```
Private Sub WriteTXTFile(TableName As String)
Dim TableRange As Range

Set TableRange = Range(TableName & "[#All]")

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim filesys, filenm, txtstrm
Dim CurrentCell As String

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filesys.CreateTextFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TableName & ".txt"
Set filenm = filesys.GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TableName & ".txt")
Set txtstrm = filenm.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateFalse)

For Each cell In TableRange
    CurrentCell = cell.Value
    txtstrm.Write (Chr(124) & CurrentCell)
Next cell

txtstrm.Close
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> "Method Range of object _Global failed."

I'm sure there's something wrong with the way the subroutine sets the TableRange, but I can't find any information on how to pass a Named Table name as a string to a subroutine and use it in a range.

Comment: Try using: `Set TableRange = Application.Range(TableName & "[#All]")`

Comment: That produced the same error but with `"_Application failed"` instead of _Global...

Comment: Then I guess at least one of the table names is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, so I just realized that my `filename` and `filenm` were wrong. I corrected them and, even though I'm still getting the `_Application failed` error, the tables are now being exported to their respective pipe-delimited TXT files. If the Range method is still failing, how could the export still succeed?

Comment: What is `myrng` in your posted code?

Comment: That's supposed to be `TableRange`, but it was also a typo in the question - it's corrected now, but still getting the error. It's not a big deal, since the data is successfully exporting, and I am able to suppress the error.